# javascript variable alone on a line, why?

Tags: javascript, popup

```
var popup = window.open('http://twitter.com');
popup;
if ($.browser.safari && !popup) {
alert('Please allow for popups on your browser.');
}
```

I came across the above code today, what (if any) is the reason for the second line "popup;" ?

Comment: Tried it on chrome it doesnt do anything special or unexpected. It may be a safari specific thing.

Comment: The second line does not do anything, you can safely remove it

Comment: While the second line does nothing, **sometimes** that syntax is used to to have somewhere to put a breakpoint.  Useful if there are no other executable lines .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line does not do anything, you can safely remove it